# CopyMemory gives segmentation fault

Tags: c++, windows, segmentation-fault, shared-memory

My program is supposed to take input via the console and use shared memory so that another process can get access to the input. 
Apparently `CopyMemory` is causing a segmentation fault.

```
    std::string Input;
    std::cout << "What Text do you want to encrypt? ";
    std::getline(std::cin, Input);   

    //create named shared memory
    HANDLE shmMapFile = CreateFileMapping(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE, NULL, 
                                            PAGE_READWRITE, 0, 256, _T("shared_mem"));

    //view the mapped memory (makes adress space visible)
    LPCTSTR shmBuffer = (LPTSTR)MapViewOfFile(shmMapFile, FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS, 0, 0, 256);

    //Copy Input into shared memory. c_str converts string to pointer to char array
    CopyMemory(shmMapFile, Input.std::string::c_str(), 256);
```

I suppose it has to do with pointers, but I could not find the cause of the error.
So where did I go wrong? Or do I use the functions incorrectly?

Thanks in advance!

Edit:
Changing `256` to the actual size of Input didn't help

Edit 2:
I tried to minimalize the problem so you can run it yourself:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>

int main()
{
    char buffer[6] = "Hello";

    HANDLE shmMapFile = CreateFileMapping(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE, NULL,  
        PAGE_READWRITE, 0, 6, _T("shared_mem"));
    if (!shmMapFile == 0)
        std::cout << shmMapFile << "(CreateFileMapping) Error: "<< GetLastError() << std::endl;


    LPCTSTR shmBuffer = (LPTSTR)MapViewOfFile(shmMapFile, FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS, 0, 0, 6);
    if(!shmBuffer == 0)
        std::cout << shmBuffer << "(MapViewOfFile) Error: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;


    if (!CopyMemory(shmMapFile, buffer, 6) == 0)
        std::cout << "(CopyMemory) Error: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;

}
```

Comment: Are you sure `Input` contains 256 characters? What if the user provided less input data?

Comment: Not necessarily, I thought that's like a maximum. I'll try using only the actual length of the given input

Comment: `CopyMemory(shmMapFile, Input.std::string::c_str(), std::min(256, Input.size()+1));` would be safer. Also check the return values from `CreateFileMapping` and `MapViewOfFile`.

Comment: @AnonPJ `CopyMemory` takes a pointer. There is no way to know from a generic pointer how big the data it points to is. This is possible with pointers to C strings because by convention those functions look for a special null character that indicates the end of the data. But generic pointers don't necessarily follow that convention and `CopyMemory` uses `void*` which indicates it operates on any pointer, not just pointers to null terminated strings.

Comment: Okay, does that mean "size" of the data doesnt refer to the amount of 0's and 1's? Because I thought different characters have different bitsizes

Comment: btw it still doesnt work. I tried @TedLyngmo 's solution and the same error occured :(

Comment: Did you also check the return values from all functions? Make a [mcve].

Comment: ```CreateFileMapping``` returns the adress (like 0x120) and ```MapViewOfFile``` returns ```NULL```. GetLastError() returns "187"

Comment: Why using Input.std::string::c_str() instead of Input.c_str()?

Comment: You are copying into the address represented by a handle, which makes no sense because handles do not represent addresses. You meant to copy into the buffer (`shmBuffer`). You also do no error checking.

Comment: Make a [mcve] and use `Input.c_str()` as DXZ said.

Comment: I edited my question with a "runnable" code. Still causes the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first argument to `CopyMemory` should be `shmBuffer`, not the handle. HANDLE is superficially a pointer datatype, but dereferencing it is a sure way to get access violation.

Comment: That worked !! Thanks. But I had to change ```shmBuffer``` to LPVOID and not cast ```MapViewOfFile``` to LPTSTR type. After those changes, it worked.